# Rails rake db:migrate aborts with generated model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration

Can someone tell me what I have done wrong?

I ran `script/generate model CityZipMSA city:string state:string zip:integer MSA:integer`

And then ran `rake db:migrate` and I get the following error

> (in /Users/MMyself/app_dev/property)
>   rake aborted!
>   An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:
>
> uninitialized constant CreateCityZipMsas

My migration file:

```
    class CreateCityZipMSAs < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :city_zip_msas do |t|
      t.string :city
      t.string :state
      t.integer :zip
      t.integer :MSA

      t.timestamps
    end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :city_zip_msas
  end
end
```

When I run `rake db:migrate --trace`

I get

> (in /Users/MMyself/app_dev/property)
>   ** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
>   ** Invoke environment (first_time)
>   ** Execute environment
>   ** Execute db:migrate
>   rake aborted!
>   An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:
>
> uninitialized constant CreateCityZipMsas
>   /Users/MMyself/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p249/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:443:in `load_missing_constant'
>   /Users/MMyself/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p249/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:80:in`const_missing'
>   /Users/MMyself/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p249/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:92:in `const_missing'
>   /Users/MMyself/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p249/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/inflector.rb:364:in`constantize'
>   /Users/MMyself/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p249/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/inflector.rb:363:in `each'
>   /Users/MMyself/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p249/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/inflector.rb:363:in`constantize'
>   /Users/MMyself/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p249/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/inflections.rb:162:in `constantize'
>   /Users/MMyself/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p249/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:374:in`load_migration'
>   /Users/MMyself/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p249/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:369:in `migration'
>   /Users/MMyself/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p249/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:365:in`migrate'
>   /Users/MMyself/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p249/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:491
>   /Users/MMyself/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p249/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:565:in `call'
>   /Users/MMyself/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p249/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:565:in`ddl_transaction'
>   /Users/MMyself/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p249/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:136:in `transaction'
>   /Users/MMyself/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p249/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:182:in`transaction'
>   /Users/MMyself/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p249/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:565:in `ddl_transaction'
>   /Users/MMyself/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p249/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:490:in`migrate'
>   /Users/MMyself/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p249/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:477:in `each'
>   /Users/MMyself/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p249/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record>/migration.rb:477:in`migrate'
>   /Users/MMyself/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p249/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:401:in `up'
>   /Users/MMyself/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p249/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:383:in`migrate'
>   /Users/MMyself/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p249/gems/rails-2.3.8/lib/tasks/databases.rake:112
>   /Users/MMyself/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p249/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:636:in `call'
>   /Users/MMyself/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p249/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:636:in`execute'
>   /Users/MMyself/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p249/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:631:in `each'
>   /Users/MMyself/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p249/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:631:in`execute'
>   /Users/MMyself/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p249/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:597:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
>   /Users/MMyself/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p249/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in`synchronize'
>   /Users/MMyself/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p249/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:590:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
>   /Users/MMyself/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p249/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:583:in`invoke'
>   /Users/MMyself/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p249/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2051:in `invoke_task'
>   /Users/MMyself/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p249/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in`top_level'
>   /Users/MMyself/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p249/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in `each'
>   /Users/MMyself/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p249/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in`top_level'
>   /Users/MMyself/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p249/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2068:in `standard_exception_handling'
>   /Users/MMyself/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p249/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2023:in`top_level'
>   /Users/MMyself/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p249/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2001:in `run'
>   /Users/MMyself/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p249/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2068:in`standard_exception_handling'
>   /Users/MMyself/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p249/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:1998:in `run'
>   /Users/MMyself/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p249/gems/rake-0.8.7/bin/rake:31
>   /Users/MMyself/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p249/bin/rake:24:in`load'
>   /Users/MMyself/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p249/bin/rake:24

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have:

> class **CreateCityZipMSAs** < ActiveRecord::Migration

And the error is:

> uninitialized constant **CreateCityZipMsas**

Try to rename your migration to **CreateCityZipMsas**.

Comment: Thank you! I knew it was probably an obvious thing I just could not see it!